Why is this question bad? And why are my comments asking for feedback deleted?
I asked How to have a fragment to both fade-in and highlight-red? and got a couple downvotes in just minutes. I asked why was that the case and the comment got deleted. I asked again and the new one was deleted as well. Why is that?

Shouldn't that question have a working, runnable code-snippet, or at a minimum explain in words why the html you show there should behave the way you expect? You only gave us html markup and the tag is the only hint we have you use some js library. But how you use it or have it configured is a guess. Given it is about a visual effect, consider after describing the behavior adding an animated gif that demonstrates the problem you described earlier.

Agree with @rene that you would have done well by providing a mre when it comes to questions about a relatively unknown framework like [tag:reveal.js]. Not tagging the question with the related language tags (in this case [tag:javascript] and [tag:css]) probably didn't help in conveying that you did your research before posting. As to why your comments got deleted, since we can't see their actual contents, probably only a moderator can answer that. However it may be, I re-tagged the question and wrote up an answer.

@RobbyCornelissen There's neither CSS nor JavaScript in the question, so I'm not sure either tag applies.  You didn't tag or mention the one language that is present in the question, which is HTML.

@RyanM I added the HTML tag too. If OP would have provided an MRE, there would have been CSS and JavaScript in the question though, as is evident by the snippets you added.

@RobbyCornelissen there is no CSS in the snippets I added, and only one line of boilerplate JavaScript.  The library itself is implemented using CSS and JavaScript, but to quote the suggested edit reviewing UI regarding when tags are relevant, "Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."

@RyanM Arguably, adding class properties to HTML counts as using CSS. But by your logic, I shouldn't tag my [tag:jquery] questions with [tag:javascript] or tag my [tag:bootstrap] questions with [tag:css]? That would drastically decrease the visibility of my question. For tags like [tag:jquery] or [tag:bootstrap] I'd probably get some views, but if I go for a more obscure framework I'd probably get very few...

The comments were deleted because asking for improvement ideas should be done here on Meta, not in the comment section.

@RobbyCornelissen class properties are independent of CSS and can be used usefully with no CSS at all (getElementsByClassName() and XPath selectors, for example), though interaction with CSS is probably the most common case for them. jQuery questions containing JavaScript should be tagged [tag:javascript], but jQuery questions containing, say, only TypeScript probably should not. (I don't know enough about Bootstrap to answer confidently about it, but just over 50% of [tag:twitter-bootstrap] questions are not tagged [tag:css].)

I thought my code is an MRE already. It seems that there is a conversation going on here, so I don't know what action I should take (or not necessarily take). When there is a conclusion can you write an answer so that what I should improve next time?

Sorry, that was mostly a tangent about tagging; as far as feedback on actions for the future, feel free to disregard any remarks about how the question should be tagged (including mine), as I'd be surprised if the tags are particularly related to the downvotes.

@RyanM so tagging properly is not a factor on counting what is an MRE or not? Yeah I didn't include the full code because I though having the [tag:reveal.js] tag alone is enough to make the MRE. I thought that if you aren't familiar with the lib, then you are unable to answer it anyway. If you are familiar, then you will have enough context, and the rest of the code is just boilerplate (i.e. not minimal enough).

Well, it would definitely not be an MRE without the reveal.js tag (but that's a moot point here because you did include it).

@Ooker "I thought that if you aren't familiar with the lib, then you are unable to answer it anyway." I hadn't heard of [tag:reveal.js] until I read the question, which I stumbled onto because of this meta question. I would have never popped up on my radar otherwise due to the absence of language tags (which I don't want to relitigate here).

Honestly, I'd be willing to guess a lot of the downvotes you got were from folks that didn't read the tags, assumed it was a straight HTML/CSS/JS question, and downvoted it because they felt like it was missing an MRE. As a person who has used RevealJS extensively, at a glance, it's a bit sparse but generally I get the gist of the inquiry. Having a preamble in the question text specifically stating that this is for RevealJS, rather than relying on the tags alone, might have been sufficient to reduce some of this misplaced negative feedback/downvotes you received. Sorry this happened :(

As far as why the question might have been downvoted...
The only real issue I can see is that your MRE could have been better in a couple ways:

It doesn't reproduce the behavior you claim it does.  That's not, strictly speaking, necessary to answer this how-to question, but it's not great.
It'd be nice (but not required) if it included a Stack Snippet reproduction (like the ones I added in).  It's a good idea for two reasons:

Had you done this, you probably would have noticed the first issue.
It makes it easier for people to test out answers without recreating a working setup from scratch (even if they do know how to do it, it's nice to not have to), making it more likely that you'll get an answer just because it's less work.



Overall: I don't know why it got that reaction; it mostly seems basically fine.  Though someone with more subject-matter expertise might spot issues that I missed.

"MRE could have been better" is a bit of an understatement if "it doesn't reproduce the behaviour". I understand answering did not need a proper MCVE, but still.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні it was a two-part MRE, with the first part (which would have been sufficient on its own) doing exactly what it said it did, and the second one reproducing the behavior of not doing what was desired, albeit not in exactly the way that the text claimed.

To answer the question about why the comments were deleted:
Comments asking why there are down votes rarely reach the people that voted that way. They already voted and moved on. New people looking at the question can only guess at the motivations of the people that came before.
Such comments don't add much other than noise. Many users will flag them as "no longer needed".  Moderators handle those flags by deleting the comments, usually without even opening the question to look at the question or surrounding comments.
For a longer discussion see Yivi's answer to Is addressing @downvoters a reason to delete a comment? and Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?
This in one of just several categories of comments that moderators summarily delete:

"Why the down votes?"
"Thank you so much!"
"I've updated my post."
"This worked for me."
"@user can you answer <other question>?"
"Please vote up and accept this." (Might also warrant a message from the moderator.)

I'd estimate that we handle a couple hundred flags for comments in these categories each day.

thanks. I found a dedicated question just for this issue: Is asking for "how to improve the question" a reason to delete a comment?. As for how mods handle flagged comments, I understand that if the comments are trivial like that they can be deleted right away. But for comments that have additional info (e.g.: "I've tried this and it doesn't work as well. I've updated that to the post."), would mods feel like the can delete right away as well?

If the comment says that it was edited into the question, I would not open the question before deleting it.  In general, comments are meant to be ephemeral.  They often get hidden behind "see more comments."  The bar for deleting them is pretty low.

@Ooker Why are you putting more info in the comments? Edit it into the question where it belongs.

@beaker say you ask me for more info. When I reply you I should state the info as well, right? Just saying "I've updated the question" doesn't feel making the conversion convenient enough to me, unless the comment format isn't well suited

@Ooker There is no need to comment that you've updated the question at all.

@beaker then how can I notify the person asking for more info that I've updated the question? Just believing that they will check even without any notification?

@Ooker How do you know they want notification? If they're interested in the outcome, they can get notifications by following the question, or they can simply check back.

@beaker I have no evidence that they want, but I also have no evidence that they don't want too. So in that case I assume that if they tell me something, then they want to know the answer. That's an tacit and reasonable expectation in my understanding. They can follow the question or check back of course, but even with when they want to do that, most won't do that as these burden their cognition.

@Ooker Comments asking for information aren't asking for the poster's personal edification. (If they are, they're using the site wrong.) They're asking for the information to be included in the question, so that it becomes more answerable by the community. Whether or not the poster is personally interested in the add'l info dictates whether they'll choose to follow the question. Remember, comments are not for conversations, and using @-mentions as a notification system is inherently an attempt to continue a conversation.

@FeRD that's not really a valid assumption; following a question tends to generate a flood of notifications when you want one.  @-mentioning someone to say that you've addressed their feedback is a perfectly reasonable practice, and generally something I would want done when users address my feedback.
